# MySQL - Complex query issue, multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out an SQL statement that I need to make.

I have 2 tables

Friends

```
===================================
friendfromid | friendtoid | request
===================================
```

Users

```
=================
userid | username
=================
```

I need to get the userid and username of each user that is my friend.

My id is either in the friendfromid or friendtoid depending on if I am requested the user or the user requested me.

So basically what needs to happen is the script needs to look at the friends table, get all the rows where my id is either friendfromid or friendtoid check that the request field is set to 1, take all the rows that fit that match then get the ids and usernames of each friendfromid or friendtoid which isn't mine.

For instance, if my id was 8 and the friends id was 9, let's say they requested me their id would be in the friendfromid field and my id would be in the friendtoid field, that means the script would take their id (9) and match it to that user in the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give friends list with friend id and friend name:

```
SELECT  u.userid , u.username
FROM Friends f 
JOIN Users u 
ON (( f.friendfromid ={the ID} AND friendtoid=u.userid)
OR ( f.friendtoid = {the ID}  AND friendfromid=u.userid))
WHERE f.request = 1
```

Put {the ID}= user id whose friend list required.

Comment: I think you mean `(friendfromid=? AND friendtoid=userid) OR (friendtoid=? AND friendfromid=userid)`.

Comment: What I mean is when `fromid` matches `toid` is the foreign key and vice-versa. Your entire join condition is equivalent to `{the ID} = userid`!

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I had to remove the double equal signs, but yes it works perfect, thank you

Comment: sorry man....by mistake i had done double equal signs.... i have removed double equal signs and placed single equal answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
JOIN friends 
ON friendfromid != userid
OR friendtoid != userid
WHERE request = 1
  AND userid = {the ID}
```

Comment: Incorrect. He wants to get the ID either from `friendfromid` or `friendtoid` where his user ID is on the opposite field.

Answer (score 1):

Can't achieve in 1 query.

To get `friendtoid` with "my user ID" in `friendfromid` field:

```
SELECT b.friendtoid FROM Users a, Friends b WHERE request=1 AND friendfromid = a.userid
```

Vice versa for `friendfromid`.

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt make any sense .... I need to get the userid and and username from the users table

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION query, joining to friends as below

```
SELECT username FROM user INNER JOIN friends ON (userid = friendfrom) WHERE friendto = {myid) AND request = 1
UNION
SELECT username FROM user INNER JOIN friends ON (userid = friendto) WHERE friendfrom = {myid} AND request = 1
```

Remember you need indexes on the friendto and friendfrom columns for performance